# Transpose in R grouping by row and column

Tags: r, transpose

How do I transpose the data-frame with the following condition in R? The normal transpose doesn't work in this case.

[Current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WITFm.jpg)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mVJO.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: look at `reshape2::dcast()`

Comment: Also `xtabs` or `tapply`, but this is a multi-duplicated quesion.

Answer (score 2):

Like that:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Tom", "Tom", "Hardy", "Hardy"), 
                 Drug=c("drug1", "drug2", "drug1", "drug3"), 
                 Value=c(20,10,30,40))
dcast(df,Name~Drug, fill = 0 )

   Name drug1 drug2 drug3
1 Hardy    30     0    40
2   Tom    20    10     0
```